# Python -- array() VS array([])

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, text-files

I have a bunch of txt files that I am importing with numpy.loadtxt(). Some of the txt files are empty and some contain numbers. For most of the imports, I get the result of loadtxt to be of type:

```
array([1])
```

for example. And then for others I get the type:

```
array(1)
```

And I am confused on the difference between these two objects. I want to use the first datatype for all of the files, but what is different about the individual text files that would make this happen?

Comment: One is an array with shape `(1,)`, the other is an "array" with shape `()`

Comment: Those aren't `types`; those are examples of `ndarray`, with different shape.  With an empty file, I get a `array([], dtype=float64)` array (and a warning).  That has a `(0,)` shape.  Before going too far with this importing, do some basic `numpy` reading.

Comment: Ok, I now understand that they are different shapes, but what would cause a text file containing only a number to be read in as array(3) vs array([3])? I have seemingly identical text files that contain a single number in them, but when using np.loadtxt(), one of the text files is read in as array([3]) and the other as array(3). I want for them both to be np.array([3]), and I am unsure what the difference in the files is.

Comment: I'd have to experiment, but the difference could be a line break.  Normally `loadtxt` is used to read a 'table' - rows of consistent columns, producing a 2d array of numbers.  Using it for a single number is overkill - a simple line read and parse would do.  But it does have a `ndmin` parameter.

Comment: I get shape `()` for a single number, regardless of nl or not.  (this is without delimiters).  I don't what is giving you shape (1,).  In any case `ndmin` may be the best way around this.

Answer (score 0):

The object is the same. The difference is the shape of it. You can try it yourself with this snippet of code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1])
print(np.shape(a))

a = np.array(1)
print(np.shape(a))
```

The output is

```
(1,)
()
```

Comment: I created text files, typed in the number 1 in them, and then loaded them in with np.loadtxt(). Some of the files load in as np.array(1) and others as np.array([1]). What do you think is the reason for this? Is it to do with the way I create the text files?

Comment: Could be anything really. Do you have a carriage return at the end of your line in some files and not in others ?

Comment: I singled out one that was causing me trouble (I want the number to be read in as array([3]) ), and I tried loading it with a return after the number and with no return after the number, both times I get the same result, array(3).